# Performance Monitor (perfmon) showing some unusual statistics

Tags: windows, performance, performance-monitoring

Recently i have thought to used perfmon.msc to monitor process utilization of remote computer.

But i am faced with some peculiar situation. Please see the below Print-screen

[image]

I have selected three computer -- QDIT049, QDIT199V6 & QNIVN014.

Please observer the processor Time % which i have marked in Red Circle. How it can be more than 100%.?

The Total Processor Time can never go above 100%, am i right?

If i am right? than why the processor time % is showing 200%

Please let me know, how it is possible or where i have done mistake.

Thanks & Regards,
Param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a computer has more than one processor, its load may be over 100%. That's a long standing peculiarity of load measurements.

This can be roughly described by the following formula:

> Total_processor_time% IS the SUM of the length of intervals that the
>   processor was executing a running process DIVIDED by walltime TIMES 100.

For example if in an interval of 0.01s

```
 process_1 was running for 0.0052s on core1 
 process_2 was running for 0.0072s on core_2 and 
 process_3 was running for 0.0022s on core_1
```

then the total_processor_time% will be

```
     (0.0022 + 0.0052 + 0.0072) / 0.01 * 100% = 146%
```